# Cortex-m0 pop instruction fails when executing in vector area?

Tags: arm, cortex-m

Is there some official reason why this instruction would fail when executing from the vector area (i.e., below address 0xC0) on Cortex-M0 but works correctly in higher FLASH?

```
pop {r4,pc}
```

When this code is executed from an address below 0xC0, the PC is not actually popped from the stack and execution proceeds with the next instruction after 'pop' (which is garbage).

Comment: what is the address popped into the program counter?

Comment: is the stack pointer aligned and pointing at the right thing?

Comment: please provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: what is the instruction after and how do you know it is being executed?

Comment: 1. No address is "popped" into the counter, the address of the next instruction is loaded in as if the instruction never happened.

2. Stack pointer is aligned and correct. The "pop" instruction is just a few instructions down from a "push" with just some MOV/CMP/BNE in between.

3. Working on minimal example.

4. The instruction after is a NOP, I can step through the code with a debugger and watch the POP succeed when at address >256, fail when at address <256.

Comment: If you can step through it then you should already see the answer.  But will wait for an example.

Comment: In the mean time can you show us the machine code for the instruction before the pop and the one after?

Comment: There is nothing special about the address space below 0xC0.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to return from an exception handler, or change the program counter from within an exception handler. 
A `pop` instruction which loads a value to the pc, or a `bx` instruction will cause the processor to return from the exception, however, it won't return to the address you pop into the pc, instead it will unwind the stack and return to the location which was pushed during exception entry. This is detailed further in the [M0 User guide - exception entry and return](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/Babefdjc.html).

If you want to return to a different location from within the exception, you could modify the stack frame which was pushed, overwriting the pushed pc with your desired location.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I was trying to do. Literally the code sequence was:

    PUSH {R4,LR}
    ...
    POP {R4,PC}

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...it is a vendor-specific issue. The FLASH space for this SoC at addresses <256 is protected and "virtual" -- it functions as exception vectors but it does not function normally (by design) for code execution or for general FLASH storage.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: please provide the part number so we can know these parts are special.

Comment: I have used a number of the major brands cortex-m parts and never seen this all of my programs have handlers down there.  this is very curious